# Generate a column indicating year and quarter

Tags: pivot-table, google-sheets

I have a column with dates for financial transactions. I'd like to group them by quarter for a pivot table report. Not quite sure how to do this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on SuperUser

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your dates are in ColumnA with Row1 a data label: insert `=if(month(A2)<10,if(month(A2)>6,"Q3",if(month(A2)>3,"Q2","Q1")),"Q4")` in Row2 of a helper column and copy down. Then use the helper column for your pivot table.